# iMacros using EVAL to replace text

Tags: imacros

How to use EVAL command to replace some text in string and return it back to different variable?

I want ti replace $ character in extracted text and any other string like ABSD or #EANF#.

I have this.

```
SET !VAR1 EVAL("var s=\"{{!EXTRACT}}\"; s.replace(/\$/g, "");")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SET !VAR1 EVAL("'{{!EXTRACT}}'.replace(/[\\$|ABSD|#EANF#]/g, '');")
```

Comment: Your question rather deals with regular expressions than with ‘iMacros’ itself. My sources are: the wiki, forums etc. and a lot of experimenting. Certainly, I use it as Firefox extension and currently for the offline tasks concerned with data base connectivity, file system accessing, running external applications.